# Datepicker - Using a default function with a custom function

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently, I have this custom function:

```
var $myBadDates = new Array(<?php foreach($aryDates as $disabledate) { echo ' "$disabledate",'; } echo " 1"; ?>);
// Creates the array (The echo " 1"; is merely to close the array and will not affect the outcome
```

```js
function checkAvailability(mydate) {
    var $return = true;
    var $returnclass = "available";
    $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', mydate);
    for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
        if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {
            $return = false;
            $returnclass = "unavailable";
        }
    }
    return [$return, $returnclass];
}
```

The datepicker section goes as such:

```
$(function () {
    //To enable End Date picker only when Start Date has been chosen (And to disable all dates prior of said date)
    var end = $('#enddate').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        stepMonths: 3,
        beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
    });
    // Defining a function, because we're binding this to two different events
    function enableEnd() {
        end.attr('disabled', !this.value.length) // Enable the end input element if the first one has anything in it
        .datepicker('option', 'minDate', this.value); // Set the minimum date to the date in the first input
    }
    //End of function
    // Datepicker
    $('#startdate').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        stepMonths: 3,
        beforeShowDay: checkAvailability,
        minDate: +1,
        onSelect: enableEnd // Call enableEnd when a date is selected in the first datepicker
    }).bind('input', enableEnd); // Do the same when something is inputted by the user
    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
});
//End of Function​
```

What I do is from my SQL DB, i use a custom function that changes a start date and an end date to an array of dates, which is then pushed into a single array and used to disable the said dates.
The second datepicker is only enabled when a valid date from the first is returned as `TRUE`.

The problem now is this:
I can block out all the dates that I have to. Great. But now, how do I block out weekends on top of this?
`beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` can't work because I'm already using a custom function. So, I have to customize my custom function even further. I can't use getDate() and show those > than 0 and < 7, so how can I tackle this?

Any help, answer of even a tip would help. I've been trying this out for sometime and I haven't gotten anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: `getDate()` won't work. Even creating a function that repeats the same procedure won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems rather simple but I fail to understand why can't you use [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function:

```
function checkAvailability(d) {
    if (
        d.getDay() == 6 /* saturday */ ||
        d.getDay() == 0 /* sunday */
    ) {
        return [false,'unavailable unavailable-cuz-its-weekend'];
    }
    $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d);
    for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
        if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
        {
            return [false, "unavailable"];
        }
    }
    return [true, "available"];
}
```

Comment: I now see that you DO NOT have to use the formatDate function in the first place. mydate *is* a date and mydate.getDate() *will* work and so will mydate.getDay() -- 0-6 for sunday thru saturday.